# Conventions Roadmap for EF7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'd like to get a clearer picture of the roadmap for Code First conventions for EF7. Presently there are three implementations of IEntityTypeConvention:

1. KeyConvention
2. PropertiesConvention
3. RelationshipDiscoveryConvention

Are there plans for achieving parity with EF6 CF conventions?  For example, I don't see something like the PluralizingTableNameC convention.  Also, what are plans for the API for customizing conventions?

Comment: Looks like custom conventions are on the backlog https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/214

Answer (score 3):

As Anthony mentioned in his comment, this is currently on our backlog to be implemented - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/214.

The API for custom conventions will likely look quite different from EF6 because of the new metadata API and our change to make ModelBuilder incrementally build a model rather than storing a bunch of configuration and then building the model when needed.